# Input Type Select value from AngularJS $scope?

Tags: html, angularjs

How show the Value on input type select when loading data from AngularJS $scope?
The ng-model is filled by controller with an ID from contactTypes

index.html

```
<select data-ng-model="item.mediumTypeId"
    data-ng-options="option.name for option in contactTypes track by option.id">
</select>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.item.mediumTypeId = 5102;
```

Option Values after loading index.html

```
<option value="5101">E-Mail</option>
<option value="5102">Fax</option>
<option value="5103">Phone</option>
```

The above Code doesn't select the option in the select field after loading index.html

Comment: What are you trying to do? Where is contactTypes in your controller? We need more info before we can you help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have:

```
$scope.item.mediumTypeId = '5102';
```

As angularjs doesn't convert it to a number automatically.

Answer (score 1):

If your controller contains something like this:

```
$scope.contactTypes = [{name: 'one', age: 30 },{ name: 'two', age: 27 },{ name: 'three', age: 50 }];
```

your template should look like this

```
<div ng-controller="Test">
  <p>selected item is : {{item.mediumTypeId}}</p>
  <select ng-model="item. mediumTypeId">
    <option ng-repeat="item in contactTypes" value="{{item.age}}">{{item.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This solution also works fine, it helps to keep the code a bit cleaner